# Implementing facebook login on android - no Logcat result after login

Tags: android, facebook

I've tried to follow the developer guide from facebook the best I could, and I came up with the following for my `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LoginButton loginButton;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.d("FACEBOOK", "onSuccess");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d("FACEBOOK", "onCancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Log.d("FACEBOOK", "onError");
            }
        });

    }

}
```

The Login button works as in taking me to the login page and I log in, it says my app requests xyz, and I click okay. The window closes, but then nothing else happens. It seems like my callback isn't working, but I'm not sure why. Does anyone see anything wrong? I read lots of people using fragments, and I'm not sure why... Is that the issue? I've been messing with android for about two days so I really don't know much.

Comment: use project given [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/HelloFacebookSample) and make your changes in  it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the onActivityResult method in your activity and call `callbackManager.onActivityResult`.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

See the [login guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android).

Comment: Thanks! That fixed a bit of it, now it switches the login button to log out after I successfully login. However, I'm still not getting logcat output that's in the callback. Do you have any other ideas of what I could try?

Comment: Hmm, that should work. Are you sure you have your logcat filters set for debug messages?

Comment: Woops, that was my problem. Thank you very much!